# Google Drive/Doc API Saving and Importing

Tags: download, google-drive-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

My website currently creates a word document for users (docx format) and sends it to them as a downloadable so they can save it to their computer.

What I would like to know is if an Open in Google Doc "Button/Feature" exists.  So instead of downloading the docx, the user could open it directly into their Google Drive and/or Google Doc account.

Is this possible?

Thanks,

Comment: I believe you should be able to achieve this using the Drive API https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads#importing_to_google_docs_types_wzxhzdk18wzxhzdk19. Additionally, you can check the "Save to Drive button" reference https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/savetodrive

Comment: Thanks, Exactly what I was looking for